# Dropdown menu aligned wrong in IE7

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu, alignment

I'm almost finished optimizing my stylesheet for IE7 (First time I've ever done it), but there still is one problem. I have a dropdown menu, which is working perfectly fine in all other browsers, including IE8+, but which is aligned wrong in IE7. For some reason, the submenu is aligned under the next menu item. For example; the submenu from item 1 is aligned under item 2, submenu from item 2 is aligned under item 3 etc.

Here's my HTML (partitial):

```
<div id="main_nav">
<ul id="main_nav_list">
   <li><a href="#">START</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Twee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Derde</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Laatste</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
    <li><a href="#">LEVEN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MOBILITEIT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">VRIJE TIJD</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS (partitial):

```
#main_nav {
float:right;
height:40px;
margin-left:6px;
margin-top:90px;
position:absolute;
width:780px;
}

#main_nav_list li {
display:inline;
min-width:100px;
position:relative;
text-decoration:none;
}

 #main_nav_list li a {
color:#222;
font-family:Absolut_Pro, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:1.1em;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:10px;
text-decoration:none;
}

#main_nav_list li a:hover {
border-bottom:2px solid #db002a;
color:#db002a;
}

#main_nav_list ul {
background-color:#FFF;
margin-top:20px;
padding-top:20px;
position:absolute; 
width:180px;
}

#main_nav_list ul li { 
background-image:url('images/list_bg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:4% 50%;
border-bottom:1px dotted #666;
float:left; 
font-size:0.7em;
padding-left:15px;
width:165px;
}

#main_nav_list ul a {
display:block;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding:5px 0;
}

#main_nav_list ul a:hover {
border:none;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: one thing I see on the first look is that for position: absolute you are supposed to use left and top (and/or right and bottom) properties, not margins... it is not always the rule that it is 0 by default.

Answer (score 1):

Add these ones:

```
#main_nav_list ul {
margin:0;
bottom:0;
left:0
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, only left:0; was necessary :)